# Using a variable in a bash script for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have a file which has the number of .pdfs in my folder. I assign this number to a variable, `fileNum` like so:

> `fileNum=$(ls -l *.pdf | wc -l)`

`echo $fileNum` returns this number without any problem.
Now I need to use `fileNum` in a for loop and I am having problems with it.

My for loop is:

> ```
> for i in {1..$fileNum}
> do
>  var=$(awk 'NR=='$i 'pdfs.file')
>
>  gs \
>  -sOutputFile="exgs_"$var \
>  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
>  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
>  -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
>  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
>  -dNOPAUSE \
>  -dBATCH \
> $var
>
> done
> ```

The `$` at the beginning of `fileNum` gives me an error message which is:

> awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {

Things are fine when I actually use the number itself (which in this case is 17).
Obviously, `awk` doesn't like this because of ... something.... I don't know what. What should I do about this?

I tried other forms such as `$(fileNum)` and `filenum` with the single quotes around it.
Is it something to do with strings?

Comment: first step: debugging: `echo 'NR=='$i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Bash will do the expansion on the braces before the variable.  You need to use eval in this case so that Bash expands the variable first.

```
for i in $(eval echo {1..$fileNum})
do
 var=$(awk 'NR=='$i 'pdfs.file')

 gs \
 -sOutputFile="exgs_"$var \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
$var

done
```

Comment: Take a look here. - http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: And here is a thread on linuxquestions.org that talks about it too. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/using-a-variable-to-control-a-bash-for-loop-737458/

Answer (score 4):

I'd use bash to read the file instead of running awk for every line.

```
while read -r file; do
    gs -sOutputFile="exgs_$file" \
       -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
       -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
       -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
       -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
       -dNOPAUSE \
       -dBATCH \
       "$file"
done < pdfs.file
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Otherwise, for the general case where you want to iterate from 1 to *n*, I'd use a C-style for-loop.

```
n=10
for (( i=1; i <= n; i++)); do
   ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather write:

```
for i in $(seq $fileNum)
do
  ....
done
```